# What is blender internal render light?

Tags: rendering

what is blender internal render and how do i make this on my warning light beacon i recently saw a video on youtube a beacon that makes cycle upon the wall,what i need to buy to do this?

Here's the video:
https://youtu.be/XYaGUv0Q9-Q

Comment: Blender internal render? That video is 8 years old so he probably talks about cycles... You dont need to buy anything, just place spot light in a place and keyframe rotation around Z axis glass object, thats all

Comment: Wait wait please i like this expain me a little slower what you mean to place and keyframe rotation around z axis glass? What exactly you mean ? Reflector is not making any cycle i have try it i cant understand what i need to do exactly

Comment: Someone please expain me with easy words how i can make this i like cycle

Answer (score 1):

This is **an animation** and to make any animation you need several **keyframes.** In your case each keyframe is a Spot light parented to an object rotated by a number of degrees. Eg. four 90° keyframes. Then you play it. For details see the documentation.

Comment: Sorry im sad now i still dont understand it can you make a video somehow and show me please?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FcuyQ4UQTas&t=174s I found this video for your problem, try to look at it